# MySQL: Extract a number, which is in one of two tables

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a query, where I need to extract a number, which is in either the first table or the second table. The query needs to be fast, because I want to do that with 4 million entries.

There are two tables, which look like that:

```
subscriber
| id1 | pileofmud                  |
------------------------------------
| 111 | xxx,yyy,number:1110,zzz    |
| 112 | xxx,yyy,nothingthatmatters |
| 113 | xxx,yyy,nothingthatmatters |

subscriber_ext
| id2 | pileofmud                  |
------------------------------------
| 111 | xxx,yyy,nothingthatmatters |
| 112 | xxx,yyy,number:11200,zzz   |
| 113 | xxx,yyy,nothingthatmatters |
```

Now I want to extract the ids and the numbers.
So the result should be:

```
| id  | num   |
---------------
| 111 | 1110  |
| 112 | 11200 |
```

The id 113 should not be in the result set, as it doesn't have a number in the column 'pileofmud'.

Unfortunately I didn't get very far here, but in pseudo-code it should look like that:

```
SELECT id1 AS id, some_string_cutting_op AS num FROM subscriber     WHERE ID IN (111,112,113,...,4000000) UNION
SELECT id2 AS id, some_string_cutting_op AS num FROM subscriber_ext WHERE ID IN (111,112,113,...,4000000)
```

The UNION in my query is unappropriate, I just wanted to give you an idea.

BTW: I would like to use conventional string operations instead of regexes, because speed matters here, it should be done for 4 mio records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want your query to be fast, then use proper database structures.  This means not dumping a lot of values into a single column, even one aptly named `pileofmud`.  Instead, normalize the data in the column using either multiple columns in the table or a junction table.

Comment: You're totally right. There was some historic growth for these data structures ;-) Unfortunately I can't change this.

Comment: Would the existence of just the ":" character in pileofmud be unique to all instances where there exists a number?

Comment: No, that's not the case. There could be fields in 'pileofmud', which could look like 'xxx,number:123,evenmore:456,whatever:789'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want, but it won't be fast:

```
select *
from ((select s.id,
              substring_index(substring_index(pileofmud, 'number:', 2), 'number:', -1) + 0 as number
       from subscriber s
       where pileofmud like '%number:%'
      ) union all
      (select s.id2,
              substring_index(substring_index(pileofmud, 'number:', 2), 'number:', -1) + 0 as number
       from subscriber_ext s
       where pileofmud like '%number:%'
      ) 
     ) s;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Just for clarity: How do I interpret the numbers in
`select (...) + 0`   (why +0) and
`substring_index(pileofmud, 'number:', 2)` (why 2, which is the count?)
?

Comment: The nested `substring_index()` call is a way of getting the second field in a delimited list.  The `+ 0` converts the value to a number, without generating an error when there are non-numeric characters.